# define string double arrow an array php

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to try update data with looping for ,this is my function controller

```
    function updatedata(){
                        if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
                            redirect('login','refresh');
                        }else{
                            $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in'); //data session
                            $idu=$session_data['id']; //get session id user
                            $exclude=array('website','id'); //exclusion column
                            $stmt_list=create_statement('user', $exclude); //function implode list fields
                            $kol=explode(',',$stmt_list);
                            $n=count($kol);
                            $data=array();
                            for ($t=0; $t < $n; $t++) { 
                                $data[]='"'.$kol[$t].'"=>"'.$this->input->post($kol[$t]).'"'; 
                            }
                            $query=$this->db->where('id',$idu) //query update table user
                                    ->update('user',$data);

                    }
    }
```

but string double arrow can't define an array , 
                I hope there are other solutions to be able to cope 
thank you alot for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using array_push, in light of the new comments.

```
array_push($data, $kol[$t]. "=> '". $this->input->post($kol[$t])."'");
```

Edited: to reflect comment changes

Comment: did you mean ,put this in the loop for ?

Comment: the extra quotes purpose for post value string to database , and variable $t as index array must be in a state of dynamic ,  how to keep the value of the array it appears ?

Comment: Yes that should go in the for loop. If that's the case then your quotes should be dealing with the values for database values. If doing that though I assume your not binding the variables and leaving yourself open to a awl injection attack but in your original statement the quotes are just a little off. $data[]= $kol[$t]."=> '".$this->input->post($kol[$t])."'"; so the merge won't work this way because you aren't making an array which the double arrow is looking for. After you have all in array just implode it

Comment: ok , I'll try and fix it and Thank you for your attention all

Comment: Also I'm pretty sure if you are using code igniter the first option with the array merge should have been the better option. It's looking for a proper array object. If you look at the update documentation for the code igniter db handler